# Deleting member of list using dropdown menu index is deleting the entire list in the save data

Tags: c#, list, user-interface, unity-game-engine, drop-down-menu

I am attempting to do a rough implementation of save data for usernames, for an android application made in Unity. This app will not be deployed and I don't need to worry about passwords for the usernames, so I am simply using the persistent data path to save a text file.

The entered usernames are added to a list of strings, and then used to populate a dropdown menu in my UI.

I am able to create the text file just fine, and save to it, and load from it. However, I am trying to implement a delete function that allows the user to delete a username they no longer wish to use, which should delete the username from the list of strings, remove it from the dropdown menu, as well as call the "Save" function that will re-save the new list to the same text file.

Currently, I have the user select the offending username from the dropdown, and then press a "Delete" button, which should use the index of the dropdown menu and delete the corresponding member in the list of strings using the "RemoveAt" function.

However, this seems to delete the entire list, and on opening the save text file, it is now empty. I believe there is something wrong with the way I am deleting the members of the list, or something wrong with the way the application re-saves the new list.

```
public class SignInManager : MonoBehaviour {

    List<string> menuOptions = new List<string>();

    //USER INPUT
    public InputField newUserName;
    public Dropdown selectedUsername;
    public string userName;
    public int dropDownOption;

    //SAVING
    FileInfo f;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    f = new FileInfo(Application.persistentDataPath + "save.txt");

    //Load existing username options here
    if (f.Exists) 
    {
        Load();
    }

    Save();

    Load();
}

//When the sign-in button is clicked
public void OnClick()
{

    if (newUserName.text != "" ^ selectedUsername.value != 0)
    {
        //Save entered user data, later export to desired location
        if (newUserName.text != "")
        {
            userName = newUserName.text;

            selectedUsername.AddOptions(new List<string> { userName }); //AddOptions must take a list as parameter, but this is just a list of one each time

            menuOptions.Add(userName);

            Save();
            Load();

            //Save data to text file here

            //Set current username to entered one

        }
        else if(selectedUsername.value != 0)
        {
            dropDownOption = selectedUsername.value; //Set current username to selected one
        }
    }

//When the user signs out
public void OnReturnClick()
{
    newUserName.text = "";
    selectedUsername.value = 0;

    userName = "";
    dropDownOption = 0;
    }

}

public void DeleteOption()
{
    if (selectedUsername.value != 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Removing: " + selectedUsername.value);

        //menuOptions.RemoveAt(selectedUsername.value);

        selectedUsername.options.RemoveAt(selectedUsername.value);

        selectedUsername.value = 0;

        Save();
        Load();

    }
}

void Save()
{
    StreamWriter w;
    if (!f.Exists)
    {

        w = f.CreateText();

        for (int i = 0; i < menuOptions.Count; i++)
        {
            w.WriteLine(menuOptions[i]);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        f.Delete();
        w = f.CreateText();

        for (int i = 0; i < menuOptions.Count; i++)
        {
            w.WriteLine(menuOptions[i]);
        }

    }

    w.Flush();
    w.Close();

}

void Load()
{
    if (f.Exists && selectedUsername != null) //don't know why selectedUsername sometimes comes up as null, but that additional condition was needed
    {
        selectedUsername.ClearOptions();
        selectedUsername.AddOptions(new List<string> { "" });

        StreamReader r = File.OpenText(Application.persistentDataPath + "save.txt");
        string line;

        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            menuOptions.Add(line);
            selectedUsername.AddOptions(new List<string> { line });

        }

        r.Close();
    }

}


}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I tried this out myself. First off, I do not see how you are getting the whole list to disappear. That did not happen to me when I tested this in Unity. Maybe when your file is disappearing you are checking for it at the path `C:\Users\Andy\AppData\LocalLow\{companyName}\{projectName}\save.txt` If you are doing that, and you have a file at that location for some reason, then that file should be empty. You list your file as `Application.persistantDataPath + "save.txt"` and Application.persistantDataPath does not return an ending . So whether this s working how you think it should or not, it would be better for your file path to be `Application.persistantDataPath + @"\save.txt"`

Second, while I was not seeing the whole list dissappear, the list and file would not update. This is because you are doing

```
        //menuOptions.RemoveAt(selectedUsername.value);

    selectedUsername.options.RemoveAt(selectedUsername.value);

    selectedUsername.value = 0;
```

While your save function does `w.WriteLine(menuOptions[i]);` You are making a change to the options, and then trying to save from the wrong list. Easy way to fix this is just it looked like you had it right the first time, uncomment `//menuOptions.RemoveAt(selectedUsername.value);` and remove `selectedUsername.options.RemoveAt(selectedUsername.value);` Afterall, your load should be making the changes to your dropdown.

Your load is also adding straight to the list, so everytime it is called, your list will get longer and longer. Your load should clear the list before it adds to it.

Also, I noticed in your save method, you are adding the name directly to the savelist and the dropdown list. This is the only reason you are seeing a change in the dropdown, as the load is not running because your f variable still thinks that the file does not exist. And your file alterations are all appending, so odd things happen to the files even when they do work. I suggest you use these changes I made:

```
    void Start()
{

    f = new FileInfo(Application.persistentDataPath + @"\save.txt");

    //Load existing username options here
    if (f.Exists)
    {
        Load();
    }

    Save();

    Load();
}

    void Save()
{
    StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(Application.persistentDataPath + @"\save.txt", false);

        for (int i = 0; i < menuOptions.Count; i++)
        {
            w.WriteLine(menuOptions[i]);
        }

    w.Close();

}


    void Load()
{
    f = new FileInfo(Application.persistentDataPath + @"\save.txt");
    if (f.Exists && selectedUsername != null) //don't know why selectedUsername sometimes comes up as null, but that additional condition was needed
    {
        selectedUsername.ClearOptions();
        selectedUsername.AddOptions(new List<string> { "" });

        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Application.persistentDataPath + @"\save.txt");
        string line;

        menuOptions.Clear();

        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            menuOptions.Add(line);
            selectedUsername.AddOptions(new List<string> { line });

        }
        selectedUsername.RefreshShownValue();
        r.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Unfortunately, I have implemented your changes, and the save file still becomes empty when attempting to delete a username from the list. I am hit with an out-of-index error when it reaches the uncommented "menuOptions.RemoveAt(selectedUsername.value);". I am not sure why the selected dropdown item isn't directly corresponding to the appropriate item in the list.

Comment: Oh yes my bad for not mentioning. Ensure that you do menuOptions.RemoveAt(selectedUsername.value-1); This is because you have index 0 of your dropdown as an empty string, but this is not saved in the menuOptions list. So by subtracting by 1, you get the correct item in menuOptions. Hopefully this also fixes the save file becoming empty.

Comment: Here is a link to the full edited version of the code you provided that did work for me when connected with 2 buttons, a dropdown, and an inputfield. https://github.com/Spookyturbo/miscellaneous/blob/master/SignInManager.cs

Comment: Actually I had assumed it was an off-by-one error, but even changing it to have -1, I still receive the out-of-index error in certain circumstances. It seems to function fine if you stop playing it after creating the file and then play again, but if I try and create and delete an item in the same run of the application, I am hit with the error.

Comment: I noticed that error as well. I fixed in my example by putting f = new FileInfo(Application.persistentDataPath + @"\save.txt"); before the exists check in the load method. My suggestion is to make sure everywhere you put the path to the file, it is the exact same, as well as also put f = new FileInfo(Application.persistentDataPath + @"\save.txt"); before any if statements that check if the file exists, as f will not dynamically update as the file changes unless you re obtain the info.

Comment: I am actually using what is essentially a copy of your posted repository, with some changes unique to my project (that have nothing to do with the file saving or the list). Does yours not reach the error at any point?

Comment: Besides not being able to add options unless the empty string is selected in the dropdown, which is intentionally in there I would assume, I do not reach an error at any point. In case something in the inspector is possibly wrong I will describe my setup. I have a canvas with a dropdown, a inputfield, and 2 buttons. The script is located on my dropdown. I dragged the dropdown into the dropdown slot, and the inputfield into the input field slot. I then made one button run SignInManger.OnClick, and one run SignInManager.DeleteOption. My dropdown also has only 1 option in the editor, being empty

Comment: I found out what the problem was! I traced my object hierarchy and compared it to yours, and found that my "Delete Option" button had an additional instance of the SignInManager script. Both instances of the script were keeping track of different lists, which caused the error in one of them. Thank you very much for all of the help!